# Android: transparent activity does not work

Tags: android, android-activity

I follow the suggestion from the below link
[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top)
In HTC Desire the activity is transparent, but in Moto MileStone(Android), it doesnot work. THe background is black. 
I change the res/values/styles.xml as below, but the background in Moto MileStone is still black

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always try setting the RGBA value of your view programatically in the OnCreate method of your activity. That might work.

Comment: i even try with an empty activity which contain only a empty linearlayout, I set its background to #00000000, it does not work.

Comment: cant you  try to set it in your activity like this:

`myourview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourlayoutID);
myourview.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

My XML file which the first activity. After clicking on the button you will be redirected to the second activity which has a button. I am giving the complete source code:

Activity 1:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button nextBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.ranjan.dibya.shadow.Next"));
        }
    });
}
}
```

Activity 2:

```
public class Next extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.next);
}
}
```

XML for activity 1:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f09473"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="Button" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

XML for Activity 2:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="This is clickable" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Next"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTranslucent" >
```

Style:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTranslucent" parent="android:style/Theme.Translucent">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.5</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

This works for me. I hope same will work for you.

**Edit:** The link you followed will result in a transparent activity with the buttons at the center figured this out by myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but I think the best way to get transparent background is to add colors.

put transparent color in hexadecimal

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp... you can check here .

click on right if you accept the answer.

any problem please post .

Comment: I even use getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0)); but it did not work too